# 'Add --> Existing Item...' dialog box from Visual studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am developing a Visual Studio extension which will be used to add a file as related item to another file as shown below.

test.aspx
-->test.js

I am able to develop the extension and able to add a file from code(using hard coded file name).

How do I invoke the 'Add --> Existing Item...' dialog box and retrieve the selected file name from void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution

We can invoke visual studio commands using _dte.ExecuteCommand method.

_dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.AddNewItem");
_dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.AddExistingItem");